# Gradle distZip task executed on Windows but ran on Linux

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using Gradle as my build configuration tool. I'm developing on my Windows desktop but the actual distribution will be run on Linux.

When I run the 'distZip' task it generates a zip file which contains a .bat file which runs fine on Windows but not on Linux.

Is there a way to configure Gradle so that it will create a Linux compatible script?

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.0.RC3")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

mainClassName="com.RestfulServer.Application"

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.1'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.1'

    // Local file dependencies
    compile files('libraries/AWS/aws-java-sdk-1.7.2.jar',
                  'libraries/AWS/third-party/joda-time-2.2/joda-time-2.2.jar',
                  'libraries/AWS/third-party/httpcomponents-client-4.2.3/httpclient-4.2.3.jar',
                  'libraries/AWS/third-party/httpcomponents-client-4.2.3/httpcore-4.2.jar')

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Comment: Show your build.gradle file...

Answer (score 1):

The distZip from the application plugin already creates shell scripts as well as .bat files. It should be in your zip file too.

Comment: For some reason I'm not finding a shell script file only a .bat file. Do I need to add some flag to my build.gradle?